# MVC - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a problem with some Ajax code I wrote for my MVC 5 project, I am trying to implement a search bar for my table using ajax but I am running into this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

This is my Partial View code which includes the JavaScript Ajax code:

```
@model IEnumerable<ToDo.Models.Venue>   

@*Search Box*@
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtSearch">
        <span class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" id="btnCustomerInc" onclick="VenueSearch();">Search</span>
    </p>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VenueName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VenueType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VenueTown)
        </th>
        <th>
            @*blank*@
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VenueName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VenueType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.VenueTown)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.VenueID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<script>
    function VenueSearch() {
        console.log("Venue Search function hit");

        var search = document.getElementById("txtSearch").value;
        console.log(search);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("VenuesTablePartialView", "Venues")',
            data: { searchString: search },
            success: function (data) {

                $('#VenueTable').html(data);
                $('#VenueTable').fadeIn("fast")

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This is my controller action for the partial view:

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult VenuesTablePartialView(string searchString)
        {    
            var venues = from v in db.Venues
                         select v;

            //Search
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                venues = venues.Where(v => v.VenueName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }


            return PartialView("_VenuesTable", venues.ToList());
        }
    }
```

[image: This image shows the error and the console messages]

Comment: That would mean that the controller action (or some filter or message handler in the pipeline) threw an exception.  Grab a tool like Fiddler and see what it returns in terms of a more detailed error message and troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Yes I looked into the controller action some more and I realized that [ChildActionOnly] was the source of my problem, I removed this line and is now working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the  `[ChildActionOnly]` line, this was causing problems as it meant that this controller action was only accessible by child requests.

```
public ActionResult VenuesTablePartialView(string searchString)
{    
    var venues = from v in db.Venues select v;

    //Search
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
       venues = venues.Where(v => v.VenueName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
    }

    return PartialView("_VenuesTable", venues.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to `system.webServer` section in `web.config` file

```
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```